# html/js how to ask the user where to download a file

Tags: javascript, html, download, popup

I would like to make an html file that contains a button that when clicked, asks the user where to download a js generated file to. For example, here is a screenshot of my firefox browser prompting me to decide where I want to save a file I am about to download off a webpage.

[image: example]

Currently my solution is the following code:

```
<script>
    function download(filename, text){
        let element = document.createElement('a')
        element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text))
        element.setAttribute('download', filename)
        element.click()
    }

    download("hello.txt","This is the content")

</script>
```

However the popup does not ask where to save the file to as seen here:

[image]

How can I replicate the first situation with JS and HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends entirely on the browser's implementation and is not something you can control with Javascript.

In this case the user would have to select save file.

Comment: What is happening in the html/js that is causing the difference in behaviour?

Comment: In the second image you don't have a save file prompt but an open file prompt

Comment: how can I change the code so that its a save file prompt instead?